# How can I install Cufflinks in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda, cufflinks

I go to Settings>Project: Python Projects>Project Interpreter and click in Install but Cufflinks is not listed. (I use Anaconda Interpreter)

I already used

`pip install cufflinks`
`conda install -c conda-forge cufflinks-py`
 `conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 cufflinks-py`
  `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 cufflinks-py`

but none works when I import the package in Pycharm.

Comment: What project interpreter is configured? Could it be that, when creating the project you also created a virtual environment?

Comment: I changed my interpreter to the local interpreter (C:\Users\'USER'\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe) and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple.

You need to go to **File>Settings>Project: Python Projects>Project Interpreter** and click on **Settings>Add...**

After that, you will choose **Virtualenv, System Interpreter or Pipenv** and then choose the interpreter that is already installed on your computer.

In my case, I changed to one System Interpreter (**C:\Users\'USER'\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe**)

If you never used this interpreter you will need re-install your packages.

Comment: How does this solve the problem, exactly? The issue is that you can't get PyCharm to recognize a Conda package you thought you installed, so the solution is to give up and abandon Conda entirely?

Comment: Using Conda interpreter you will not find Cufflinks package to install for some reason that I didn't understand because in Jupyter Notebook you can use the command `pip install cufflinks` and use the package normally but in Pycharm it didn't occur. When you change the interpreter you are able to install Cufflinks normally

Comment: _you will not find Cufflinks package to install for some reason..._ Whether or not a library is available on PyPi tells us nothing about it’s availability as a Conda package, so I’m not sure I understand what you mean. For what it’s worth Cufflinks seems to be available on Conda under the name [cufflinks-py](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cufflinks-py), although only for Linux.

Comment: It only works to me when I changed my interpreter to a python interpreter (Virtualenv or System Interpreter). Using Conda interpreter didn't work and I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

You can add the conda-forge Repository to Pycharm. 
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/
works like a charm, no fiddling needed.

After you add the repository you need to refresh the package list, it might take some minute or two , but will now search in conda-forge repositorys as well.